# Why isn't this template compiling?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering why if I assign the template variable to an identifier/variable it compiles, yet if I just try to access the inner static variable of the class it fails to compile:

```
template <typename component_category_t>
struct GetComponentTypeID
{
    static inline int count = 0;
    template <typename component_t>
    static inline int ID = count++;

};

int i = GetComponentTypeID<int>::ID<float>; // Works
GetComponentTypeID<int>::ID<float>; // Fails

//GetComponenIDType<int>::ID<float> is not a static member
//expected a declaration
//expected an identifier
//GetComponentIDType is not a template
```

I'm trying to have a system where:

```
classname<int>::ID<float> == 0;
classname<int>::ID<char> == 1;
classname<int>::ID<double> == 2;
classname<char>::ID<double> == 0;
```

But I'm having trouble understanding why the compiler complains when I write it like that.

Comment: Is that `// Fails` line in global namespace?

Comment: You can only have declarations in the global namespace. Not arbitrary code.

Comment: `GetComponentTypeID<int>::ID<float>;` is an expression statement. You cannot have expression statements outside of functions.

Comment: Also `count` must be wrapped in a function: `static int &count() {static int ret = 0; return ret;}`, otherwise there's no guarantee that it will be constructed before all the `ID`s.

Comment: Interesting - I tried to run this, but for me, it already fails at the line `static inline int count = 0;`, with `ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'GetComponentTypeID<component_category_t>::count'`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why is there no guarantee? The count static member comes before all the ID template members, it should be initialised in order. That goes for global namespace and in classes, isn't it? Static members are initialised line by line.

Comment: @Aziuth Did you include `inline`? What is your compiler?

Comment: @Zebrafish I'm reading part (1) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization) and for static members of class templates it doesn't mention the declaration order at all.